# Issues building and running in Xcode 8.2.1

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I am writing a macOS app on my iMac running 10.12.2.  I started writing the app right around when Xcode 8 came out and its been working fine.  It uses two 3rd party frameworks (Audiokit and SQLite) and all was well until I updated to Xcode 8.2.1.

Now the project builds successfully, but immediately says its finished running, without actually launching the app.  This same project runs fine on my laptop running 8.2.  I've done the following:

- Made sure my build scheme looked right
- Completely uninstalled Xcode, then reinstalled
- Remove and then re-add the frameworks
- Cleaned the session
- Cleaned the build folder

I'm hoping there something simple I haven't tried.  When I create a new project it builds, but any of my existing projects won't build.  When I look at the report navigator tab it days this under debug "Message from debugger: unable to attach"

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well I just deleted my developer certificate from my iMac, then reset it in the Xcode settings and that seemed to fix the issue.

Comment: I have the same behaviour, but no developer certificate to delete. No Project runs anymore!

Comment: just double check in the Keychain Access app and select certificates on the left hand side.  Are you having issues with mac apps or iOS apps?

Comment: no problem with other apps. I deinstalled LittleFlocker - which was also disabled before. Till now no problems after a reboot